# scraping tabla web

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hola quiero raspar una tabla o los datos de una página web desde 1930 hasta 2019 para una estación mmmx de manera mensual, pero no paso de la siguiente línea de código:

```py
    import requests, re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

    page = requests.get("https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/mx/mexico- 
                        city")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    seven_day = soup.find("div",{"class":"small-12 columns"})
    table = seven_day.find_all("table",{"class":"days"})
    tonight = table[0]
    CountingSort(tonight)
    print(tonight.prettify())
```

y me sale el siguiente error: IndexError: list index out of range
la variable tabla al imprimirla me sale vacia.

Comment: Me temo que se trata de una página dinámica. Es decir, la tabla que pretendes raspar no viene en la respuesta html, sino que se solicita posteriormente desde el navegador ejecutando código javascript que hace llamadas asíncronas (AJAX) para obtener la información y montar la tabla manipulando el documento "en memoria" en el propio navegador

Comment: abulafia, tendría o se podría con javascript? y me imagino que si se puede sería un trabajo difícil o con un buen nivel de programación.

Comment: Tienes dos alternativas: usando las herramientas del navegador y el inspector de red, tratar de descubrir qué peticiones hace esa página una vez cargada, para descubrir a qué URL pide los datos de la tabla, y usar esa URL desde python. Pero esta página es horrible, carga miles de cosas continuamente debido a la publicidad. Veo muy difícil dar con ello. La otra opción es usar `selenium` desde python para "teledirigir" un navegador real, que sea quien cargue la página, y ejecute todo. Y después desde python acceder al HTML ya modificado por el navegador.

Comment: Gracias abulafia, voy a ver con selenium y ya preguntare mis dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contenido se carga dinámicamente desde [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) .

[image]

La consulta (xhr):

[image]

Cambiar mes

```
2018070120180731
```

por año

```
2018010120181231
```

Generar todas las fechas (sin datos antes de 1972)

```
date_ranges = [str(year) + '0101' + str(year) + '1231' for year in range(2019, 1971,-1)]
```

La API requiere una clave encontrada en un archivo javascript.

```
r = s.get('https://www.wunderground.com/bundle-universal/index.d10d5f637f8cba449c4f.js')
api_key = p.findall(r.text)[0]
```

Haga una solicitud web para todos los años y combine resultados

---

py

```
import requests, re
import pandas as pd

p = re.compile(r'n\.key="(.*?)"')
date_ranges = [str(year) + '0101' + str(year) + '1231' for year in range(2019, 1971,-1)]
results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://www.wunderground.com/bundle-universal/index.d10d5f637f8cba449c4f.js')
    api_key = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    start_year = date_ranges[0]

    for year in date_ranges:
        r = s.get(f'https://api-ak.wunderground.com/api/{api_key}/history_{year}/lang:EN/units:english/bestfct:1/v:2.0/q/MMMX.json?showObs=0&ttl=120').json()
        data = r['history']['days']
        if start_year == year:
            columns = list(data[0]['summary'].keys())
        if data:
            for day in data:
                row = {column:day['summary'][column] if column !='date' else day['summary']['date']['iso8601'][:10] for column in columns}
                results[row['date']] = row
        else:
            row = {column:None for column in columns}
            results[year] = row

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df = df.T
df = df[columns]
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
#df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado QHarr, por mucho eres la mejor respuesta a mi pregunta, pregunte a varias personas y unos de plano me dijeron que no se podía, estoy analizando todo lo que me pusiste para entenderlo., al correr el py me da el siguiente error: ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: prueba la edición

Comment: Listo QHarr!: tenia problemas con la versión de python, pero ya quedo, una ultima pregunta. ¿que herramienta es la de la primera imagen?.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open  empujar F12 en el navegador

Comment: Estimado QHarr, perdona que te interrumpa de nuevo: porque luego no se descargan todos los años, se brinca algunos años, cuando verifico en la pagina principal de manera manual, algunos años de los que no se guardan con la API, si salen en la pagina. saludos

Comment: ¿que fechas por ejemplo?

Comment: 2007, pero cuando ejecuto de nuevo el Py, ahora si lo carga., cuando pruebo con otra estación igual no me carga algunas fechas, ejecuto el py de nuevo y me carga algunas fechas que faltaron. Saludos

Comment: Hola QHarr,el código me hicste funciono muy bien, ahora intento correrlo y me sale el siguiente error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: creo que ya no esta el archivo de javascript donde se encuentra la clave

Comment: Dame 2-3 dias p f

Comment: QHarr, como no sí me has ayudado mucho!!

Comment: https://www.wunderground.com/bundle-next/6-es2015.002cd6130a78daeda544.js  y p = re.compile(r'sunApiKey:"(.*?)"') y https://api.weather.com/v1/location/MMMX:9:MX/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20190101&endDate=20190131

Comment: ^^ creo. necesitará calcular max y min

Comment: QHarr, entonces el error era que cambiaron los archivos o ya no hay una API como tal?

Comment: Si. Mira https://stackoverflow.com/a/59477625/6241235

Comment: use el mismo código que antes para generar todas las fechas y luego use un `for` loop...

Comment: Hola. Dame 2-3 dias. :-)